# How to use $ in R to select a column with space in its colname?

Tags: r

As mentioned in the title, I would like to select a column with name "Avg Estimates" in a dataframe. How can I do this by using "$" operator? Thank you!

Comment: I guess we don't mark duplicates any more.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Nope, there's no reputation to be gained from that. :)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Yes, but then the reputation boost goes to the wrong person

Comment: @RichardScriven, can you easily find the dupe?  (I always have trouble searching for dupes where the "key words" are `$` and `[[` ...)

Comment: not *identical* to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-variable but very very close ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using `` as in

```
df$`Avg Estimates`
```

Comment: In fact, backticks (\`), single quotes ('), and double quotes (") can all be used.  Other options include `'$'(df, 'Avg Estimates')`, `df[['Avg Estimates']]`, and `'[['(df, 'Avg Estimates')`, and `get('Avg Estimates', df)`